# SQL Server CE scipt error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-ce

Can someone help me, what's here wrong?

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SZ_2017
REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST ((szamla_brutto) AS MONEY),1), '.00',''),
REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST ((szamla_netto) AS MONEY),1), '.00','')
```

The error:

```
Error Code: 80040E14  
Message   : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = ( ]  
Minor Err.: 25501  
Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider  
Num. Par. : 2  
Num. Par. : 8  
Err. Par. : (
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you are trying to do is:

```
SELECT * 
,      REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST ((szamla_brutto) AS MONEY),1), '.00','')
,      REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST ((szamla_netto) AS MONEY),1), '.00','')
FROM   SZ_2017
```

If you want to get rid of decimal values you can do it easier like:

```
CAST(CAST(szamla_brutto AS INT) AS MONEY)
```

Remember to store data in an appropriate datatype, if you store monetary values, store it as `MONEY` or `DECIMAL`, **NEVER** as (n)varchar!

Additionaly, since `convert` and `cast` are functionally synonyms, pick one and stick with it, don't mix them together.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! And can you tell me, how to override the column with the name szamla_brutto, szamla_netto with the "REPLACED" varchars? So i dont want plus columns with there varchars. Many thanks!

Comment: You'd better do some research on that, that question has been asked on stackoverflow before. If you get stuck, don't hesitate to post a new question.